# Create Page number X of Y in word via Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-word, page-numbering

I want to add a page X of Y numbering in a word file generated via Delphi which is:
- not bold; 
- in font size 8; 
- aligned to the right.

Note that:
Y is the total number of pages;
X is the index of the page number.

So far I've found this:

```
procedure Print;
var v:olevariant;

v:=CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
v.Documents.Add;
HeaderandFooter;
firstpage:=true;  

procedure HeaderandFooter;
var adoc,:olevariant;
begin
adoc.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Font.Size := 8;
adoc.Sections.Item(1).Footers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add(wdAlignPageNumberRight);
```

I can change the format of the numbering:
        adoc.Sections.Item(1).Footers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.NumberStyle := wdPageNumberStyleLowercaseRoman;

But there is no option for page X of Y format. How do I implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is not a selectable header page-numbering style which has this format, you can do this by adding specific MS Word Document Fields, the PAGE and NUMPAGES ones, to the page header (or footer), or elsewhere.

```
procedure TForm1.MakeDocWithPageNumbers;
var
  MSWord,
  Document : OleVariant;
  AFileName,
  DocText : String;
begin
  MSWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  MSWord.Visible := True;

  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  DocText := 'Hello Word!';
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(DocText);

  if MSWord.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone then
      MSWord.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close;
  if (MSWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView) or (MSWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView) then
      MSWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type := wdPrintView;

  MSWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView := wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText( Text:='Page ');

  MSWord.Selection.Fields.Add( Range:= MSWord.Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, 
    Text:= 'PAGE  \* Arabic ', PreserveFormatting:=True);
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText( Text:=' of ');
  MSWord.Selection.Fields.Add( Range:=MSWord.Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty,
    Text:= 'NUMPAGES  \* Arabic ', PreserveFormatting:=True);
  MSWord.Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1);

  AFileName := 'd:\aaad7\officeauto\worddocwithheader.docx';
  Document.SaveAs(AFileName);
  ShowMessage('Paused');
  Document.Close;
end;
```

I've left setting the font size and right-alignment as exercises for the reader as SO isn't supposed to be a code-writing service ;=)

Comment: Works like a charm!
I right aligned it via:
<code>MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphRight; </code>